# Should we have single character tags for specific commands?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we want to have tags like [x](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x) Or possibly group them together, like [hjkl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hjkl), or an [aaiioo](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aaiioo)? (aside: apparently tags are not case sensitive)

They could be synonymed to things like [delete](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete), [movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movement), or [insert-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-mode) respectively.

They could also be prefixed with like [command-x](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-x) instead of [x](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x).

Answer (score 12):

I don't think that these make too much sense. They can be synonyms at some moment, but the primary tags should be **descriptive**, as you suggest:

- [navigation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation) for [hjkl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hjkl)
- [delete](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete) for [x](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x)
- [insert-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-mode) or [insert](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert) for [iao](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iao)

If we ever decide for having tags for the most common commands, I would certainly opt for [command-x](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-x) rather than [x](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x).

Answer (score 12):

No, I think that such tags would be too cryptic to be useful.  Why [hkjl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hkjl) instead of [hjkl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hjkl)?  Also, case-sensitivity is a problem.  Furthermore, they either presuppose that the person asking the question knows the solution, or encourage the asker to ask an excessively narrow question.

I'd much rather have [cursor-movement](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cursor-movement) than [hkjl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hkjl).

Comment: [tag:hjkl] vs [tag:hkjl] = typo. I type on a Dvorak keyboard ;)

Comment: @durron597 Thanks for helping to make my point.  =)